# Presto using decimal values in query when data type of column in Big Int

Tags: apache-spark, hive, presto

We have a bucketed, partitioned hive table with 100 columns. One of the columns, say x, has datatype as `BIGINT`. We insert data into the table using a spark application. When we query the table using x as a filter, with integer values `select * from table where x = 1000` in hive-cli or spark-sql, we get the right response. But in presto, we get 0 rows. When we add a `.0` at the end, we get the right response `select * from table where x=1000.0`. What could be the cause? We tried casting the column explicitly in spark before insert. We got the same result.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce with Trino CLI. Try something like (`select * from table where x=(cast 1000 as bigint)`).

Comment: @GuruStron, we tried something similar ```select * from table where (cast x as bigint)=1000```. It does solve the issue. But we cannot request all users of the table to use the cast and this filter is probably used in almost all queries involving this table.

Comment: what is returned for `select typeof(x) from table`?